# java deadlock degrades performance

Tags: java, tomcat, deadlock, logback

We run a web application with java7 and tomcat7. In our application the performance suffered quite suddenly. The average response time doubled and in peak times the problem even got worse.

We printed out a thread dump and found a thread sitting around waiting forever for a condition. We did several thread dumps and the state of this thread never changed.

```
"logback-66215" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f86f4115800 nid=0x3758 waiting on condition [0x00007f868d817000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00007f8ddf241fa8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:925)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The references in this thread to 0x00007f868d817000 and 0x00007f868d817000 were not found in the thread dump.

After restarting tomcat the thread was gone and performance was like it should be.

We are running it on a server with 12 Cores. We monitor CPU usage but saw no spike. When in peak load because of about 500 requests/second the CPU usage did go up to 800% but did not increase further up to 1200% (which is the maximum). It just stopped increasing when it reached 800% and then the performance problems were really bad of course.

I don't understand enough about the internals of threading, CPU, interrupts to fully understand this situation. I really would like to understand this problem on a deeper level.

Now my question: Can someone explain me, why a deadlock like this causes so much trouble? Why does it not show up in CPU usage, so we see a fully loaded CPU? Or is it just a problem about context switching?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on the thread dump above, and the presence of a SynchronousQueue, I'd guess that you're using a CachedThreadPoolExecutor (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`) to execute some tasks.

So the dump would be that of one of the cached threads, simply waiting for a job to be enqueued in the threadpool. Nothing wrong here, this is not a deadlock - a real deadlock would be explicitely stated as such in the thread dump anyway.

As for the CPU consumption, a thread put in the WAITING state does not consume any CPU cycles - it isn't even scheduled for execution.

So, where does your performance problem come from ?

Hard to say, but if I were you, I'd avoid using a CachedThreadPool, as it will diligently create as many threads as needed to execute the jobs, even if it means eating all your server's memory (each thread has reserved memory for its stack, which is at least 100k) and CPU (your scheduler will turn crazy if there are too many threads to manage).

You may want to manually configure a ThreadPoolExecutor (as opposed to using the `Executors.new*` factories), to be able to choose the maximal number of threads, size and type of queue, and backoff strategy in case of a big bulk of jobs coming.